# monitoring nginx-plus vhost trafic with munin

Tags: nginx, munin

I am using nginx-plus (the version you have to pay for) and I would like to monitor acces by vhost.

When I used nginx free version, I could easily monitor accesses with the [byprojects](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/blob/master/plugins/nginx/nginx_byprojects/byprojects_access) munin plugin:

[image]

I migrated to nginx plus and I have no data. When I log vith netcat to munin node :

```
$ nc localhost 4949

# munin node at servername.com
fetch byprojects_access
controlcenter.value 0
static.value 0
ccapi.value 0
tracking.value 0
reco.value 0
```

The main difference is I am logging via syslog when I was logging to file. Each vhost logs with a tag, here the tag `nginxreco` :

```
access_log syslog:server=localhost,facility=local7,tag=nginxreco,severity=info;
```

Where I had the following log to file configuration under free nginx:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/reco-access.log;
```

So, for the `reco` vhost for instance, I had to adapt [plugin](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/blob/master/plugins/nginx/nginx_byprojects/byprojects_access) configuration from :

```
'reco' => [
            {'path' => '/var/log/nginx/reco-access.log'}
          ],
```

to

```
'reco' => [
            {'path' => '/var/log/local7.log', 'regex' => 'nginxreco'}
          ],
```

Since I use syslog, log format changed a little bit: it adds a date, a hostname and a tag (which is the syslog way to log)

Old format (from direct file):

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [18/Mar/2014:06:25:20 +0100] "GET /HTTP/1.1" 200 52 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
```

New format (from syslog):

```
Mar 18 06:25:20 myhostname nginxreco: xx.xx.xx.xx - - [18/Mar/2014:06:25:20 +0100] "GET /HTTP/1.1" 200 52 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

local7.log was not readable by munin